# Triple DES encryption decryption in c programming using openssl using file IO

Tags: c, pointers, encryption, openssl

I am trying to do Triple DES encryption of text file input.txt and save encrypted data to output.txt. Then again in same program, I am decrypting the output.txt and saving it to recovered.txt.

The encryption works. But recovered.txt is not getting exact output as input.txt

What am I doing wrong here ?
Screen-shot contains example input/output

[image: My input.txt output.txt and recovered.txt. recovered.txt should be same as input.txt]

Here is my code

```
#include <openssl/des.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DES_BLOCK_SIZE 8


FILE *fp;
FILE *rp;
FILE *op;
size_t count;   
char * buffer;
int bytes_read, bytes_written;
unsigned char indata[DES_BLOCK_SIZE]; 
unsigned char outdata[DES_BLOCK_SIZE];

DES_cblock cb1 = { 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE };
DES_cblock cb2 = { 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE };
DES_cblock cb3 = { 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE, 0xAE };

DES_key_schedule ks1;
DES_key_schedule ks2;
DES_key_schedule ks3;

DES_cblock cblock = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

void encrypt(){ 
  DES_set_odd_parity(&cblock);


      fp=fopen("input.txt","a+b");
      op=fopen("output.txt","w");
      if (fp==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}   
      if (op==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}      

while (1) {     

    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, DES_BLOCK_SIZE, fp); 

    DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(indata, outdata, DES_BLOCK_SIZE, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3,&cblock, 1);
    bytes_written = fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, op); 
    if (bytes_read < DES_BLOCK_SIZE) 
    break; 
  }   

  fclose (fp); 
  fclose (op);
  free (buffer); 
}

void decrypt(){
  //Opening files where text cipher text is read and the plaintext recovered   
  memset(cblock,0,sizeof(DES_cblock));      
  DES_set_odd_parity(&cblock);

  rp=fopen("recovered.txt","w");
  op=fopen("output.txt","a+b");
  if (rp==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}   
  if (op==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);} 

  //Initializing the encryption KEY
  while (1) {     

    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, DES_BLOCK_SIZE, op);

    DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(indata, outdata, DES_BLOCK_SIZE, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, &cblock,0);
    bytes_written = fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, rp); 
    if (bytes_read < DES_BLOCK_SIZE)
    break; 
    }   
  fclose (rp); 
  fclose (op);
  free (buffer); 
}

int main() {

  encrypt();
  decrypt();  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only the last block is corrupted, which make me think that it might be a padding problem

Comment: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PRINT SCREEN</kbd> will allow you to snap an image of the Gedit window, rather than the whole desktop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [openssl c++ 3DES file encryption decryption fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528995/openssl-c-3des-file-encryption-decryption-fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have side-effect issues as you don't handle the last block correctly if it is not as long as `DES_BLOCK_SIZE`

I guess:

```
DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(indata, outdata, DES_BLOCK_SIZE, // ...
```

Should be:

```
DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, //...
```

Indeed when you have `bytes_read < DES_BLOCK_SIZE`, you still asking for encrypting/decrypting a string of size `DES_BLOCK_SIZE` so you are going out of bounds.

Have a look [there](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/114504/): it might help.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested you code, here's some point you need to pay attention to:

**Encryption**

- Use PKCS#5 padding scheme, [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/DES-JDK-What-Is-PKCS5Padding.html) is a simple explanation
- Always write DES_BLOCK_SIZE amount of data as encryption output, since you've done the padding

**Decryption**

- Make sure you always read DES_BLOCK_SIZE amount of data as input
- Strip the padding before you write to file